# ANTLR: Lexer does not recognize token

Tags: antlr, antlr3, lexer, parser-generator

Given the following Lexer grammar:

```
lexer grammar CodeTableLexer;

CodeTabHeader   : '[code table 1.0]';
Code            : 'code';
Table           : 'table';
End             : 'end';
Row             : 'row';
Naming          : 'naming';
Dfltlang        : 'dfltlang';
Language        : 'english' | 'german' | 'french' | 'italian' | 'spanish';
Null            : 'null';

Number
    : Int ('.' Digit*)?
    ;

Identifier
    : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '$' | '.' | Digit)*
    ;

String
@after {
    setText(getText().substring(1, getText().length() - 1).replaceAll("\\\\(.)", "$1"));
}
    : '"' (~('"'))* '"'
    ;

Comment
    : '--' ~('\r' | '\n')* { skip(); }
    | '/*' .* '*/'         { skip(); }
    ;

Space
    : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | '\u000C') { skip(); }
    ;

fragment Int
    : '1'..'9'
    | '0'
    ;

fragment Digit
    : '0'..'9'
    ;
```

... the following parser grammar:

```
parser grammar CodeTableParser;

parse
    : header^ begin (row)* end EOF
    ;

header
    : CodeTabHeader
    ;

begin
    : Code Table Identifier row
    ;

row
    : Row (Number | Identifier) value
    ;

value
    : (Identifier (Number | Identifier | String))+
        (Naming Dfltlang String (Language String)*)?
    ;

end
    : End Code Table
    ;
```

... and finally the following source to parse:

```
[code table 1.0]

code table my_table
row 1
    id              "my_id_1"
    name            "my_name_1"
    descn           "my_description_1"
    naming
        dfltlang    "My description 1"
        english     "My description 1"
        german      "Meine Beschreibung 1"

row 2
    id              "my_id_2"
    name            "my_name_2"
    descn           "my_description_2"
    naming
        dfltlang    "My description 2"
        english     "My description 2"
        german      "Meine Beschreibung 2"

end code table
```

I always get error message

```
line 1:0 extraneous input '[code table 1.0]' expecting CodeTabHeader
```

I’m a bit confused… token CodeTabHeader is defined as ‘[code table 1.0]’ in my lexer; am I missing something? Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
J3d

Comment: Try change _CodeTabHeader   : '[code table 1.0]'_; on CodeTabHeader   : _'[code table 1.0]\n'_;

Comment: @CAMOBAP, no, that can't be it. `\n` is discarded by the lexer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you split the lexer and parser in two different files, explicitly indicate in the `options`-block of your parser which tokens it should use:

```
options {
  tokenVocab=CodeTableLexer;
}
```

Comment: Sorry... but the missing "Table" is just a typo (I've just fixed it in my post). Anyway, the original grammar file was correct. The error you get is because the code table name is "my_table", which contains the word "table" (this is another issue in my example: if an identifier contains a reserved word, then the parser complains). If you rename it to "mystuff", you'll get exactly the same error message as I did.

Comment: Found... If I've put the lexer and parser into the same file, the everything works fine; as soon as I use two separate files (CodeTableLexer.g and CodeTableParser.g), I get the error I mentioned in my post. Is there anything I should take care when working with separate files (one for the lexer and another one for the parser)?

Comment: Thank you very much! I also read your tutorial... great work - I think it is the best tutorial around. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there any way to iterate through a resulting StringTemplate? What I need to do is to parse two different versions of the same source and re-arrange them so that the common part comes first and the rest at the end. I saw the walker example in your tutorial... but I'm wondering if there is an easier way to manipulate sources in memory. [What I'm trying to do is a tool that aims to facilitate merging activities].

Comment: @j3d, sorry, missed your comment. I've not much experience with StringTemplate: best create a separate question about that and tag it with both `antlr` and `stringtemplate`. Good luck!