# Antlr4 lexer takes wrong rule

Tags: antlr, antlr4

My language has commands that can be parameter-less or with parameters, and an "if" keyword:

```
cmd1            // parameter-less command
cmd2   a word   // with parameter: "a word" - it starts with first non-WS char
if cmd3         // if, not a command, followed by parameter-less command
cmd4 if text    // command with parameter: "if text"
```

"if" is recognized as `if` only if it's the first non-WS string in the line (let's ignore comments for now...)

These are my grammer rules:
    grammar TestFlow;

```
// Parser Rules:
root: (lineComment | ifStat | cmd )* EOF;

lineComment : LC;
ifStat  : IF;
cmd : CMD;

// Lexer Rules:
LC  : '//' ~([\n\r\u2028\u2029])* -> channel(HIDDEN); // line comment

IF  : 'if';

CMD : [-_a-zA-Z0-9]+ GAP LINE
    | [-_a-zA-Z0-9]+
    ;

fragment GAP    : [ \t]+;
fragment LINE   : ~([\n\r\u2028\u2029])*;
```

But my lexer identifies 3rd line as a `CMD`: `if cmd3`, and not as `if` followed by `cmd3` as I need.

What's my mistake? how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just little tiny line, made everything perfect: in my `MyParser.g4`, just had to enter:

```
options { tokenVocab = MyLexer; }
```

right after the `parser grammar MYParser;`...

So much time was wasted just to find this little detail... :-(

---

(few of the) Other posts of people not knowing what was going on, just to finally reach this solution:

- [ANTLR: Lexer does not recognize token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603326/antlr-lexer-does-not-recognize-token/12609823#12609823)
- [mismatched Input when lexing and parsing with modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027201/mismatched-input-when-lexing-and-parsing-with-modes)

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be a parser rule in your example that defines the grammar. Meaning there is no rule indicating to look for an 'if' AND a command.

What is happening in your words:

> But my lexer identifies 3rd line as a CMD: if cmd3, and not as if followed by cmd3 as I need

The first alternative in the lexer rule CMD looks for one or more characters ("if"), followed by a space ' ', followed by a LINE (cmd3). 
So, with the input "if cmd3" it matches the entire line, which is exactly what you told it to do!

I can tell you from personal experience that for even a simple language, you'll learn a **lot** and very quickly by taking a step back and review some example grammars, which is what I would do if I were you now to avoid frustration. I **highly** recommend the Antlr4 REference book from www.pragprog.com as well as the antlr website.

**UPDATED**
I think this is what you may be interested in:

```
grammar myGrammar;

root        :   statement NEWLINE
            | comment NEWLINE
            ;

statement   :   ifStat (LC)?
            | cmdStat (LC)?
            ;

ifStat      :   IF cmdStat;
cmdStat     :   cmd (args)*;

cmd     :   CMD;

args        :   LINE;
CMD     :   [-_a-zA-Z0-9]+ GAP LINE
            | [-_a-zA-Z0-9]+
        ;

fragment GAP    :   [ \t]+;
fragment LINE   :   ~([\n\r\u2028\u2029])*;
NEWLINE     :   ('\r')?'\n';
```

Again, I must say, if you read the book (which I did), this may give you the expected response from your parser (not lexer). 
The ifStat is optional (may ormay not be there, based on your test cases), there will always be a cmd and there may or may not be a line comment following it. Try this out and see if it is helpful. Good luck!

Comment: I initially excluded the parser rules, as it seemed to me like a lexer issue. Anyway, I updated my question to include the parser rules, if it helps. 2nd thing: the `IF` rule appears before `CMD`, so I'd assume it takes precedence.

Comment: If you're referring the "The Definitive ANTLR4 Reference" book, then I have it, but it's not a very good "getting started" tutorial.

Comment: `root :  ((ifStat)? cmd (lineComment)?)* EOF;` doesn't work either. The thing is that `if cmd3` appears as a single token as I get from `commonTokenStream.getTokens()`. So if it is a single token, this is what the parser gets from the lexer, it can't divide them. This is why I assume it is a lexer issue, and not parser

Comment: Did you test it? because it still doesn't seem to work